# SQL Left Join and Computed Column not producing desired results

Tags: sql, join, linq-to-sql, calculated-columns

I believe I'm way off base here but I'm not sure the best approach to take. I have a products table and a reservation table. I need to evaluate on the fly the availability of products based on their reservations for a certain time frame. There could be multiple reservations for each product but my results should just be the product table with a computed column for it's availability.  Here's what I have so far but the left outer join isn't what I need. I'm sure there's a better approach with my case statement and eliminating the join.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAvailableReservations]
(     
    @StartDate DateTime,
    @EndDate DateTime
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT p.*, 
        CASE
            WHEN r.Status = 'Active' AND r.StartDate >= @StartDate AND r.EndDate <= @EndDate 
                THEN 'Reserved'
            WHEN r.Status = 'Primary' AND r.StartDate >= @StartDate AND r.EndDate <= @EndDate 
                THEN 'Sold'
            WHEN r.Status = 'Primary' AND r.StartDate >= DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE()) AND r.EndDate <= GETDATE() 
                THEN 'Refused'
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.URL u WHERE u.URL = p.URL AND u.Date < DATEADD(YY,-2,GETDATE())) 
                THEN 'Needs Review'
            ELSE 
                'Available'
        END AS Availability
    FROM dbo.Product AS p 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Reservation AS r
    ON p.Name = r.Title
)
```

I would like this to be a function to call in linq-to-sql and then I can query off of the list of products with their availability.

Edit - Here's some sample data below.

```
Products:
Name    URL                         Cost
-------------------------------------------
Gears   http://www.gearfinder.com   250
Shocks  http://www.shockfinder.com  110
Bolts   http://www.boltfinder.com   5



Reservations:
Title   Status        StartDate     EndDate
----------------------------------------------
Gears   Active        2012-01-01    2012-12-31
Gears   Primary       2012-01-01    2012-12-31
Gears   Inactive      2012-01-01    2012-12-31
Bolts   Inactive      2011-01-01    2011-12-31
Bolts   Active        2013-01-01    2013-12-31
Bolts   Primary       2014-01-01    2014-12-31

URLs:
URL                         Date
--------------------------------------
http://www.shockfinder.com  2010-01-01
```

Comment: What's the question? Don't you know how to call a UDF in LINQ-to-SQL? You're not very specific.

Comment: My question is regarding the function itself and whether the join and case statement are the best approach for computing a column on the fly. I just wanted to give an overall account of why I am taking this approach in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, if you don't expect more than 9 statuses per product:

`SELECT p.name, 
       SUM(CASE
            WHEN r.Status = 'Active' AND r.StartDate >= @StartDate AND r.EndDate <= @EndDate 
                THEN 10000
            WHEN r.Status = 'Primary' AND r.StartDate >= @StartDate AND r.EndDate <= @EndDate 
                THEN 1000
            WHEN r.Status = 'Primary' AND r.StartDate >= DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE()) AND r.EndDate <= GETDATE() 
                THEN 100
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.URL u WHERE u.URL = p.URL AND u.Date < DATEADD(YY,-2,GETDATE())) 
                THEN 10
            ELSE 
                0
        END) AS Availability
    FROM dbo.Product AS p 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Reservation AS r
    ON p.Name = r.Title
    GROUP BY p.name`

If you get a score of 0 then it is available. A score like 10210 means that you have 1 reserved, 0 sold, 2 refused, and 1 needs reviewed. If you can provide a sample dataset we might be able to tweak this query a little better. This will not work if you can have more than 9 of any one status for any p.name for the queried time frame.

Another option, place every status into it's own column:

`SELECT p.name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN r.Status = 'Active' AND r.StartDate >= @StartDate AND r.EndDate <= @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Reserved',
        SUM(CASE WHEN r.Status = 'Primary' AND r.StartDate >= @StartDate AND r.EndDate <= @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sold',
        SUM(CASE WHEN r.Status = 'Primary' AND r.StartDate >= DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE()) AND r.EndDate <= GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Refused',
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.URL u WHERE u.URL = p.URL AND u.Date < DATEADD(YY,-2,GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Needs Review',
        Count(*) AS 'Total Recs'
    FROM dbo.Product AS p 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Reservation AS r
    ON p.Name = r.Title
    GROUP BY p.name`

This should give you a count of every status type regardless of how many you have for each.

Comment: I keep receiving the following error, **Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery**. I would like my end results to be the product table + an Availability column. This way I can call it in my code (linq-to-sql) and run queries against it and bind it to a grid.

Comment: The logic of the query should check if that product exists in the reservation table and if so first check if the reservation status is _Active_ for the date ranges. If it is, then that Availability takes precedences. If not, then it checks the reservation status to see if it's _Primary_ for the date range... If it doesn't exist in the reservation table, check the URL's date in the URL table if it's older than two years the Availability is _Needs Review_. Lastly, if none of these are the case, then that product is _Available_.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine. Not sure about how optimal it is though.

```
SELECT p.*,
    CASE
        WHEN 'Active' IN (SELECT r.Status FROM dbo.Reservation r WHERE r.Title = p.Name AND r.StartDate >= @StartDate AND r.EndDate <= @EndDate)
            THEN 'Reserved'
        WHEN 'Primary' IN (SELECT r.Status FROM dbo.Reservation r WHERE r.Title = p.Name AND r.StartDate >= @StartDate AND r.EndDate <= @EndDate)
            THEN 'Sold'
        WHEN 'Primary' IN (SELECT r.Status FROM dbo.Reservation r WHERE r.Title = p.Name AND r.StartDate >= DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE()) AND r.EndDate <= GETDATE() )
            THEN 'Refused'
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.URL u WHERE u.URL = p.URL AND u.Date < DATEADD(YY,-2,GETDATE())) 
            THEN 'Needs Review'
        ELSE 
            'Available'
    END Availability
FROM dbo.Product AS p
```